# Firebase getDownloadURL() is really slow at getting image URLs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a page which displays multiple (12+) objects in components, each of which has an image. This image has a `src` attribute, which I'm setting via a call to my Firebase storage:

```
this.props.storage.child('Land.jpg').getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
            var img = document.getElementById('imageGoesHere'+this.state.currentId);
            img.src = url;
        }.bind(this))
```

The `storage` prop is generated and passed down by a parent component:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref("");
```

The `storageRef` var is passed as a prop to each child component that calls the `getDownloadURL()` function.

This works, but the `getDownloadURL` function seems to be really slow. The page renders, and then each image takes at least a second to be shown/rendered. I know it's not the raw URL's issue, since I can get the raw URL and paste it into the `src` and it loads fine (i.e. nearly instantly); I look at the Network tab in chrome devtools and it shows at least a second between the `getDownloadURL` call and the response. Is this the proper way of getting images to be shown in web pages? The Firebase Storage docs don't mention any other way.

edit: Two things; firstly I only have 5 test images in the storage, so it's not like I'm syncing to a whole bunch with the root storage ref.

Second thing; chrome devtools shows me that it's "stalling" for 1-4 seconds, and the actual request only takes 100ms tops. What can cause stalling?

Comment: Performance is always going to be dependent on network connection. Can you set up a jsbin that reproduces the performance problem, so that I can check what performance I get vs what you get?

Comment: you can only fetch 4-10 images at a time,. depending on browser.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen because you are downloading every single image you have every time this code runs. It can happen if you sync the instance to the entire image hierarchy.

You could also figure out the reason by looking at Chrome's Network tab, and see if you have tons of files downloading, like this:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, it's 12+ images, but I need an image for each of my items, and since I'm rendering search results, sometimes I get a bunch of them. Looking closer at the Timings tab in chrome devtools, it looks like it's stalling anywhere from 2 to 4 seconds...

Comment: @IronWaffleMan where you able to solve this problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the firebase public url when the image is uploaded (if you doing that way). Something like this:

```
uploadTask.then(function(snapshot) { return snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL() })
```

And save it to the DB inmediatly. Just create an "images" table and create a column named "url" or "link". That url/link you will use every time you need that image.

---

Now if you are uploading manually , select the image (in firebase console) and in the "file location" section, go to "access token".